# Erro ao salvar no Banco de Dados

Tags: java, spring

Fala pessoal, tenho duas classes que se relacionam veiculo e categoria, logo todo veiculo está relacionado a uma categoria (N:1),quando tento cadastrar um veiculo gera um erro como se não houvesse uma categoria no banco de dados, estou fazendo a inserção via Postman, segue o erro retornado ao chamar o método:

"object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing"

Obs: a classe categoria já está cadastrada no banco

Desde já obrigado!

Segue as classes, ocultei os métodos padrões para o código não ficar muito grande.

```
///Models 

@Entity
public class Categoria implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String descricao;
    private String nacionalidade;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoria", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Veiculo> veiculos = new ArrayList<>();



    @Entity
public class Veiculo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String placa;
    private String cor;
    private String modelo;
    private String fabricante;
    private Integer numPortas;
    private String chassi;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate ano;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Situacao status = Situacao.DISPONIVEL;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoria_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Categoria categoria;

  ///Controllers
@RestController
@RequestMapping("categoria")
public class ControleCategoria {

    @Autowired
    private CategoriaService service;

    @PostMapping("salvar")
    public ResponseEntity<CategoriaDto> cadastrar(@RequestBody @Valid Categoria categoria,UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder) {
        
        
        this.service.salvar(categoria);
        URI uri = uriBuilder.path("salvar{id}").buildAndExpand(categoria.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(new CategoriaDto(categoria));      
    }


@RestController
@RequestMapping("veiculo")
public class ControleVeiculo {
    
    @Autowired
    private VeiculoService service;
    
    @PostMapping("cadastrar")
    public ResponseEntity<Veiculo> cadastrar(@RequestBody Veiculo veiculo ,UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder) {
          
         this.service.salvar(veiculo);
        URI uri = uriBuilder.path("salvar{id}").buildAndExpand(veiculo.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(veiculo);
      
    }
    }

///
Repositorios


@Repository
public interface VeiculoRepository  extends JpaRepository<Veiculo, Long>{   

}


@Repository
public interface CategoriaRepository extends JpaRepository<Categoria, Long>{

    

}

///Serivces
@Service
public class VeiculoService {
    @Autowired
    private VeiculoRepository repository;
    public Veiculo salvar(Veiculo veiculo) {
            veiculo.setId(null);

        return repository.save(veiculo);

    }

}

@Service
public class CategoriaService {

    @Autowired
    private CategoriaRepository repository;

    public Categoria salvar(Categoria categoria) {
        categoria.setId(null);
        return repository.save(categoria);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui arrumar aqui, o problema não estava no código e sim na forma que eu estava inserindo os dados via PostMan, segue a solução.

```
{
        
    "placa":"placa",
    "cor": "cor",
    "modelo":"modelo",
    "fabricante":"fabricante",
    "numPortas":"4",
    "chassi":"e4et4trrg563ewdf3",
    "ano":"10-05-2020",
    "categoria":{
        "id":"3"
    }
}
```